# I want to extract a formula for x from this formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to express the second formula in terms of $x$ using variables $a$ and $c$.
I used to do stuff like this in high school, but for the life of me, I can't remember how to do it.

$b=a+x$,

$c = \left(15000 \left(b+\frac73\right) + 15000\left(a+\frac73\right) \right) \frac{b-a}{2}$.

edit1502111027: I think I have not been clear. I can get this far:

$c = \left(15000 \left(b+\frac73\right) + 15000\left(a+\frac73\right) \right) \frac{b-a}{2}$.
$c = \left(15000 \left(\left(a+x\right)+\frac73\right) + 15000\left(a+\frac73\right) \right) \frac{\left(a+x\right)-a}{2}$.
$c = \left(15000 \left(a+x+\frac73\right) + 15000\left(a+\frac73\right) \right) \frac{x}{2}$.

but after that, I can't figure out how to get the formula to:
x=[something]
A and C are known variables. I'm trying to get a formula that, when I plug a and c into it, it gives me x. ie. a=47,280 c=484,587,181,155. plugged into the formula, I want it to give me x=678.386736307002.

edit1502111338: 
Thank you to vikram, for doing most of the work to do this.

I used what I call 'the monkeywrench approach' (as in, I feel like a monkey with a wrench, pounding on something till it works) on what vikram gave me, because I still don't understand it. However, it almost gives the correct number. Given two positive values for u and w, it should give a positive number. Instead, it gives a negative number, the absolute value of which is the expected result.

I switched the names of the variable, to avoid confusion.
a->u
b->v
c->w

original formula
00) $w = \left(15000 \left(v+\frac73\right) + 15000\left(u+\frac73\right) \right) \frac{v-u}{2}$

substitute formula for v into equation.
01) $w = \left(15000 \left(u+x+\frac73\right) + 15000\left(u+\frac73\right) \right) \frac{u+x-u}{2}$

u+x-u=x
02) $w = \left(15000 \left(a+x+\frac73\right) + 15000\left(u+\frac73\right) \right) \frac{x}{2}$

term1 x term2 + term1 x term3 = term1 x (term2 + term3);  (I did not know this before)
03) $w=15000\left( u+x+\frac{7}{3}+u+\frac{7}{3}\right)\frac{x}{2}$

combine terms
04) $w=15000\left( 2u+\frac{14}{3}+x\right)\frac{x}{2}$

divide both sides by 15000
05) $\frac{w}{15000}=ux+\frac{14x}{6}+\frac{x^2}{2}$

?? I have no idea how six jumped around like that
06) $\frac{w}{15000}=\frac{6ux+14x+3x^2}{6}$

term1 x term2 + term1 x term3 = term1 x (term2 + term3)  ??6 jumps again
07) $\frac{6w}{15000}=(6u+14)x+3x^2$

simplify $\frac{6w}{15000}$
subtract $\frac{w}{2500}$ from both sides
08) $3x^2+(6u+14)x-\frac{w}{2500}=0$

google quadratic equation, and see:
99) $ax^2+bx-c=0$ is the same as $x=\frac{-b±\sqrt{b^2-4ac})}{2a}$

apply monkey wrench

$a=(3)$
$b=(6u+14)$
$c=\frac{w}{2500}$

$3x^2+(6u+14)x-\frac{w}{2500}=0$ is the same as $x=\frac{-(6u+14)±\sqrt{(6u+14)^2-4(3)\frac{w}{2500}}}{2(3)}$
$x=\frac{-(6u+14)±\sqrt{(6u+14)^2-4(3)\frac{w}{2500}}}{2(3)}$
$x=\frac{-(6u+14)+\sqrt{(6u+14)^2-\frac{12w}{2500}})}{6}$

Oddly enough, wikipedia says $x=\frac{-(6u+14)-\sqrt{(6u+14)^2-\frac{12w}{2500}}}{6}$ should give the same result, but it drastically does not.

If anyone can please explain to me what happens in steps 6, 7, and 99, I would greatly appreciate it. If not, thank you all for your help, I now have a working formula, even if I don't understand *why* it works.

Comment: replace all $b$'s by $a+x$...

Comment: can you rewrite it in $\LaTeX$ please?

Comment: @Dr.-Sonnhard-Graubner I would try, but I don't have a GB free on my computer.

Comment: @Surb what is the problem with the parentheses? I can't find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$c = \left(15000 \left(b+\frac73\right) + 15000\left(a+\frac73\right) \right) \frac{b-a}{2}$

$c = \left(15000 \left(a+x+\frac73\right) + 15000\left(a+\frac73\right) \right) \frac{a+x-a}{2}$

$c = \left(15000 \left(a+x+\frac73\right) + 15000\left(a+\frac73\right) \right) \frac{x}{2}$

$c=15000\left( a+x+\frac{7}{3}+a+\frac{7}{3}\right)\frac{x}{2}$

$c=15000\left( 2a+\frac{14}{3}+x\right)\frac{x}{2}$

$\frac{c}{15000}=ax+\frac{14x}{6}+\frac{x^2}{2}$

$\frac{c}{15000}=\frac{6ax+14x+3x^2}{6}$

$\frac{6c}{15000}=(6a+14)x+3x^2$

$3x^2+(6a+14)x-\frac{c}{2500}=0$

Now use quadratic formula.

Comment: I used what I call 'the monkeywrench approch' (as in, I feel like a monkey with a wrench, pounding on something till it works)  
  
a->u  
b->v  
c->w  
I swiched the names of the variable, to avoid confusion.  
  
$w = \left(15000\left(v+\frac73\right)+15000\left(u+\frac73\right)\right)\frac{v-u}{2}$  
[...]  
$3x^2+(6u+14)x-\frac{w}{2500}=0$  
Now use quadratic formula.  
[**TO BE CONTINUED**]

Comment: $x=\frac{-b±(b^2-4ac)^0.5)}{2a}$  
$a=(3)$  
$b=(6u+14)$  
$c=\frac{w}{2500}$  
$x=\frac{-(6u+14)±sqrt{(6u+14)^2-4(3)\frac{w}{2500}}}{2(3)}$  
$x=\frac{-(6u+14)+((6u+14)^2-\frac{12w}{2500})^0.5)}{6}$  

I still don't understand it. However, it almost gives the correct number. Given two positive values for u and w, it should give a positive number. Instead, it gives a negative number, the absolute value of which is the expected result.  
  
Oddly enough, wikipedia says $x=\frac{-(6u+14)-((6u+14)^2-\frac{12w}{2500})^0.5)}{6}$ should give the same result, but it drastically does not.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. The comment section squished everything I said together, so I restated it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

$${2c \over 15000x} = x+2a+{14 \over 3}$$

Answer (score 0):

It's easy! Just replace every instance of "$b$" in the second equation with "$a + x$". You can do this because since $a + x = b$, they're synonymous and can be freely interchanged.